# CRM - How to create a plugin for Update message

Tags: c#, plugins, crm

So I created a plugin, based on the given example by Microsoft on the [PLUGIN WALKTHROUGH](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg695782.aspx). It is actually on Create message, so I modified some codes and registered it under Update message.

But when I register it on Update, an exception is thrown that says:

```
System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException: The given key was not present in the dictionary.
```

So I tried to register it under Create message, and it works.

But I need to register it under update, and I can't find a reliable source on how to change my code so Update can handle it. Here is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.ServiceModel;
using Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk;
using Xrm;

public class Plugin : IPlugin
{
    public void Execute(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        IPluginExecutionContext context = (IPluginExecutionContext)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IPluginExecutionContext));

        Entity entity;

        if (context.InputParameters.Contains("Target") && context.InputParameters["Target"] is Entity)
        {
            entity = (Entity)context.InputParameters["Target"];

            if (entity.LogicalName != "scs_barangayclearanceapplication") { return; }
        }
        else
        {
            return;
        }

        try
        {
            IOrganizationServiceFactory serviceFactory = (IOrganizationServiceFactory)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IOrganizationServiceFactory));
            IOrganizationService service = serviceFactory.CreateOrganizationService(context.UserId);

            //var id = (Guid)context.OutputParameters["id"];

            SendEmailToContact(service, entity.Id);
        }
        catch (FaultException<OrganizationServiceFault> ex)
        {
            throw new InvalidPluginExecutionException(
            "An error occurred in the plug-in.", ex);
        }
    }

    private static void SendEmailToContact(IOrganizationService service, Guid id)
    {
        using (var crm = new XrmServiceContext(service))
        {

            var testData = crm.scs_barangayclearanceapplicationSet.Where(b => b.Id == id).First();

            string sr = testData.scs_ServiceRequestNumber;

            var note = new Annotation
            {
                Subject = "Created with plugin",
                NoteText = " Service Request ID = " + id + " Service Request Number = " + sr,
                ObjectId = testData.ToEntityReference(),
                ObjectTypeCode = testData.LogicalName
            };

            crm.AddObject(note);
            crm.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}
```

I really need your help. Thanks!

Comment: do you have a specific question? The only real difference between firing on create/update is what attributes you have access to...

Comment: apologies, didn't read the question....the error suggests you are trying to access an attribute that doesn't exist. Can you explain this line? `var testData = crm.scs_barangayclearanceapplicationSet.Where(b => b.Id == id).First();` Also are you registering pre or post?